# Zero width reference for borrow checking only?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

My goal is to enforce an invariant in my code using the borrow checker at zero-cost. However, to make it zero-cost, it seems like I'd need to have a zero-width reference. Here's the context:

I want to make make a factory for some objects, with a way to invalidate all the objects at once.

```rust
/// Example struct.
/// In my real code, there's stuff in here,
/// but its unnecessary for the question I'm asking.
struct Obj;

/// A struct that lets you build new `Obj`s
struct ObjFactory;

impl ObjFactory {
    /// makes a new object
    fn make(&self) -> Obj {
        Obj
    }

    /// enforce that there are no objects from this ObjFactory
    fn recall(&self) {
        // ?????
    }
}
```

The rules I want are the same as the rules that the borrow checker enforces, so I added some dummy references that make the borrow checker follow the invariant at compile time.

```rust
/// new placeholder struct that should take up no space
struct Dummy;

/// Example struct.
/// Now has a dummy reference so the compiler knows when to get mad
struct Obj<'a>(&'a Dummy);

/// A struct that lets you build new `Obj`s
struct ObjFactory {dummy: Dummy}

impl ObjFactory {

    /// makes a new object
    fn make(&self) -> Obj {
        // let the `Obj` immutably borrow the dummy
        Obj(&self.dummy)
    }

    /// enforce that there are no objects from this ObjFactory
    fn recall(&mut self) {
        // mutably borrow `dummy`, which means that Obj's can't borrow it anymore.
        let _borrow = &mut self.dummy;
    }
}
```

Now, the compiler can detect when the invariant is broken:

```rust
fn main() {

    // make factory
    let mut obj_factory = ObjFactory{dummy: Dummy};

    // create an object
    let obj = obj_factory.make();

    // uh oh! no objects are allowed!
    obj_factory.recall();

    // obj lasts until the end of the function
    core::mem::drop(obj);

}
```

The compiler correctly detects that there's an object that exists when `recall` happens.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `obj_factory` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
3 |     let obj = obj_factory.make();
  |               ----------- immutable borrow occurs here
4 |     obj_factory.recall();
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
5 |     core::mem::drop(obj);
  |                     --- immutable borrow later used here
```

This works exactly the way I want; however, it isn't zero cost. Even though each `Obj`'s dummy is zero width, it still takes up space in the `Obj`:

```
print!("{}", std::mem::size_of::<Obj>()); // 8
```

How should I go about getting the space usage of `Obj` down to `0`, while also making the borrow-checker enforce the `ObjFactory` invariants?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Rust, how do you explicitly tie the lifetimes of two objects together, without referencing eachother?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219258/in-rust-how-do-you-explicitly-tie-the-lifetimes-of-two-objects-together-withou)

Comment: @trentctl The way I see it, I'm not just trying to tie the lifetimes together, I'm also trying to take advantage of the mutable / immutable borrow shennanigans from the borrow checker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PhantomData` to have an empty type with a lifetime:

```
use core::marker::PhantomData;

/// Example struct.
struct Obj<'a>(PhantomData<&'a ()>);

/// A struct that lets you build new `Obj`s
struct ObjFactory;

impl ObjFactory {
    /// makes a new object
    fn make(&self) -> Obj<'_> {
        Obj(PhantomData) // the PhantomData has the same lifetime as `self`
    }

    /// enforce that there are no objects from this ObjFactory
    fn recall(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    // make factory
    let mut obj_factory = ObjFactory;

    // create an object
    let obj = obj_factory.make();

    // uh oh! no objects are allowed!
    obj_factory.recall();

    // obj lasts until the end of the function
    core::mem::drop(obj);
}
```